# How could I use multiple str_replace?

Tags: php

I need use `str_replace` to remove some chars of a string. To do this I'm trying use a lot of str_replace at once.

How could I do this ?

```
<?php

  //I need this result 1000.00

  $value = "R$1.000,00";
  $newValue = str_replace("R$","",$value).str_replace(".","", $value).str_replace(",",".", $value);

?>
```

**Edit:** I would like to get this result 1000.00

Comment: Do that recursively.

Comment: I think you're not thinking out of the box. I think, what you need is a method that returns only the numbers in a string... Am I right?

Comment: looking for sth like that? - http://codepad.org/nfOV8Zhi

Comment: I just want know how could I use one or more `str_replace` in same string, for example, in Java I use: ` myString.replaceAll("\\.","").replace(",","."); `. How could I do this in PHP ?

Comment: what result are you looking to get?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I want to get this result `1000.00`. I have this value `R$1.000,00`.

Comment: you can also try using number_format() http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php and probably str_pad() http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$value = "R$1.000,00";
$newValue = str_replace("|","", strtr($value, "R$.,", "|||."));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php
http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

`R$.` are first converted to *Pipes* `|||` and `,` to `.`.   `str_replace` than removes the `|`

Comment: perfect. Thanks a lot !

Comment: This does not remove `R`, `$` and `.` from the string, but replaces it with other characters: Two leading spaces and a null character. The length of the resulting string will actually be 10, not 7. Because of the null character, `intval($newValue)` will actually return `1` and not `1000`. Is this really what you wanted to do?

Comment: Now `intval($newValue)` will return `0`. Not that much better :)

Comment: 1:1 copy of my code to start with. Really?
If you do decide to put my code in there, then you should at least give proper attribution. But I don't see how copying an other answer does any good in the first place. If you think my answer is better - consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with `str_replace` use two arrays for `$search` and `$replace` as pointed out in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$value = "R$1.000,00";
$newValue = str_replace(array(".",",","R","$"), array("","."), $value);
```

Answer (score -1):

str_replace can accept an array.

```
$new_value = str_replace($value, array('R$', '.', ','), ' ', $string);
```

alternatively, if you want to replace some characters with blanks and some with other characters (where you replace "," with "."), you can do multiple instances of str_replace on the same string or you can write 2 of these with two values.

```
$new_value = str_replace($value, array('R$', '.'), ' ', $string);
$new_value = str_replace($value, array(',', '.'), ' ', $string);
```

I don't really know of a way to chain multiple commands like js but that's not to say it isn't possible.

**EDIT** I posted this before your edit. The second solution would work to accomplish what you're asking.